# Trigger not working via client input: Koa, MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, triggers, forms, koa

So, i have a CUSTOMER table:

```
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Customer_ID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Customer_FName | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Customer_LName | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Address        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Phone_No       | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And a Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER No_Of_Customers 
AFTER INSERT ON CUSTOMER
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @flag=0;
IF(new.Customer_ID % 2 = 0) THEN
    SET @flag=1;
ELSE
SET @flag=0;
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

(I use the @flag value later to display a message to the client, according to it's value for each Customer who registers.)

I'm using Koa (NodeJS), and HTML forms for the server side and client side respectively.

**The issue is:** When i enter values into the table via terminal, the trigger works and the value of `@flag` changes accordingly. But when i enter values via the HTML forms, the value gets inserted into the table, but the value of `@flag` doesn't change ie the trigger just does not work.

The Koa code for inserting value to the table:

```
router.post('/customer', async function (ctx, next) {
await insertCustomer(ctx, next);
}

async function insertCustomer(ctx, next){
    const { fname, lname, addr, phone } = ctx.request.body;
    const results  = 
    await insert('insert into CUSTOMER(Customer_FName, Customer_LName, Address, Phone_No) values(?, ?, ?, ?)', [fname, lname, addr, phone]);
}

function insert(mysqlQuery, params) {
const escapedParams = 
params.map((param) => connection.escape(param).replace(/'/g,""));
return query(mysqlQuery, escapedParams);
}

function query(mysqlQuery, params) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(mysqlQuery, params, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            reject(error)
        }
        resolve(results)
    });
  })
}
```

The form part:

```
<form action="/customer" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name*" name="fname"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" name="lname"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address*" name="addr"><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone No*" name="phone"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit.">
</form>
```

I have not been able to find an issue similar to mine.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: if you want a column that alternates 0/1 why dont you just MOD the primary key by 2 when you query the table?

Comment: if `SELECT customer_id % 2 as flag FROM customer` "doesnt work" i'd say you have bigger problems

Comment: @CaiusJard I don't want a column.
I just want a flag which sets to 0 if the entered Customer_ID is odd and 1 if even.
I'm later using this value in rest of my code to display it.

Comment: Your trigger is working. Just try to do something else like setting a column value in your table - which is also one way to solve your problem (another way is Caius's `select`). What's not working is reading that flag. While you didn't show the code to read it (which might be faulty), the problem is probably that a variable is only valid during a session ("as long as the connection is open"). It will lose its value if you close the connection, and has an arbitrary value if you use a connection pool. Both usually happens for every new html request, but not for the mysql client/terminal.